# rxjava behaviorsubject delete/clear value

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

I have an application that uses `BehaviorSubject` as memory storage for some value. This value is setting on app start based on the result of REST API request if the user is logined OR during user login.
But when the user is do logging out, the BehaviorSubject keep old value. Is there any way to clear the `BehaviorSubject` and force it have `hasValue()` as false on demand?

Comment: you can set a new 'not logged in' value with `onNext()`, so new subscribers will get the new value

Comment: solved via restarting application process, as far as it was simpler. just in case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is no.

Once a Subject receives at least one value `hasValue` will always return true. A usual trick in those cases is to have a wrapping class. Here's an example with `Optional`:

```
Subject subject = BehaviorSubject.<Optional<String>>create()
// add
subject.accept(Optional.of("Hello"))
// "clear" value
subject.accept(Optional.empty())

// check
subject.value.isPresent()
```

Comment: @Simon not necessarily. You can simply create your own Optional class

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way to do it is to create a `BehaviorSubject` from list out of 1 element. Once you want to remove it, just do:

```
val subject: BehaviorSubject<List<YourObject>> = BehaviorSubject.create()
subject.onNext(emptyList())
```

But I would support the idea, that this kludge is wrong. There must be more elegant solution.